# linq query which will return single values and a list in one call

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have this linq call:

```
PropertyViewModel propertyModel = null;
    propertyModel = (from property in db.LoanProperties
                    join tenant in db.Tenants
                    on property.PropertyId equals tenant.PropertyId
                    where property.LoanApplicationId == newApplication.LoanId
                    select new PropertyViewModel(
                        propertyModel.AddressLine1 = property.AddressLine1,
                        propertyModel.AddressLine2 = property.AddressLine2,
                        propertyModel.TotalRentPerAnnum = property.TotalRentPerAnnum,
                        propertyModel.Tenants = db.Tenants.Where(s => s.PropertyId == property.PropertyId).ToList()
                        ));
```

My view model:

```
public class PropertyViewModel
    {
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public decimal? TotalRentPerAnnum { get; set; }
        public List<TenantViewModel> Tenants { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to cast the tenants under the property from the linq query in my TenantViewModel.

How can I achieve that?

I'm referring to the last line for `propertyModel.Tenants`.

Comment: then add a .select on the end of it, and cast it

Comment: so whats the actual issue?

Comment: `db.Tenants.Where(...).Select(t => new TenantViewModel { ... }`

Comment: Why you are joining properties and tennants then again querying `db.Tennats` seperately `db.Tenants.Where(s => s.PropertyId == property.PropertyId).ToList()`?

Comment: @AdliMammadov that first join can go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. I guess you were looking for mapping your Tenant database object with your TenantViewModel?

```
ropertyViewModel propertyModel = null;
    propertyModel = (from property in db.LoanProperties
                    join tenant in db.Tenants
                    on property.PropertyId equals tenant.PropertyId
                    where property.LoanApplicationId == newApplication.LoanId
                    select new PropertyViewModel(
                        propertyModel.AddressLine1 = property.AddressLine1,
                        propertyModel.AddressLine2 = property.AddressLine2,
                        propertyModel.TotalRentPerAnnum = property.TotalRentPerAnnum,
                        propertyModel.Tenants = db.Tenants.Where(s => s.PropertyId == property.PropertyId).Select(t => new TenantViewModel {//map your properties}).ToList()
                        ));
```

Comment: thanks, I'm getting ambigious invocation error when doing this https://i.gyazo.com/83facce6b077a98d790e8069b729df82.png

Comment: @Laziale shouldn't you be using the curly brackets for creating TenantViewModel object instead of round brackets?

Answer (score 2):

it's my first answer !! hope it's help :

The objects Tenants and LoanProperties must have a [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520(v=vs.100).aspx) with the Foreign key PropertyId. So, a LoanProperties object must have a list of Tenants.

I prefer the [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) as you used on the last line (clean/clear code).
Try this :

```
var propertyModel = db.LoanProperties
        .Where(p => p.LoanApplicationId == newApplication.LoanId)
        .Select(p => new PropertyViewModel(){
                AddressLine1 = p.AddressLine1,
                AddressLine2 = p.AddressLine2,
                TotalRentPerAnnum = p.TotalRentPerAnnum,
                Tenants = p.Tenants.Select(t=> new TenantViewModel(){TenantType = t.TenantType , //other properties...})
                })
                //you don't have to query again, the tenants are already in the LoanProperty objects
                //you just have to transform it on ViewModel with a Select
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, in your constructor method of PropertyViewModel, you don't have to put `propertyModel.--- = ----.` it's useless.

Comment: @Laziale, As woodykiddy said, you should use new TenantViewModel(){TenantType = p.tenantType}. I edit